# Multiple match query with unique return

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access

I have no idea where to start with this query. I have two tables, table A with employeeID and jobclassID, and travel B with jobpositionID and jobclassID. In table A employee ID is unique but there are multiple employees with the same jobclassID.  In table B jobpositionID is unique, and jobclassID is not unique.

Example:
Table A

```
employeeID     jobclassID  
Joe            Usher  
Debbie         Cashier  
John           Usher  
Julie          Usher
```

Table B

```
jobpositionID   jobclassID
Usher1          Usher
Cashier1        Cashier
Usher2          Usher
Usher3          Usher
Manager1        Manager
Supervisor1     Supervisor
Janitor1        Janitor
Janitor2        Janitor
```

I would like to get a return like this:

```
employeeID      jobpositionID
Joe             Usher1
Debbie          Cashier1
John            Usher2
Julie           Usher3
```

It does not matter which jobpositionID an employee gets except that it is in their jobclassID. I am using MS Access to query an Oracle database.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Only way I know will result in all ushers assigned as Usher1, all janitors as Janitor1, etc. How would that be useful?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you need to do it a specific way but I will tell you a way that it should work. This is a difficult situation because there is no foreign key relating the tables. But since you said that it doesn't matter which jobpoistionID a person gets, it might work. I'm going to provide a method that will insert what you want into a new table. NOTE: I know how to do this when an online database is connected as an individual linked table. Please let me know how you have connected to Oracle if my code doesnt work. I am going out on a limb here, but if you can give me a good description of how you connected to oracle, then i can provide a more accurate answer.
For the purposes of my answer I will pretend that the name of the database is dbo_Oracle but you will need to replace what I write with the real name exactly as it appears. The same is true for "Table A" and "Table B" in your example. If those are not the actual name then you must change them in my code to reflect their actual names

Try this:
Step1: Create a new table, let's name it newTable
Now create three columns: employeeID, jobclassID, and jobpositionID
(you do not need a primary key for this table)

Step 2: Go To: File>>Options>>Trust Center>>Trust Center Settings>>Macro Settings>> And select "Enable all Macros..."
(You can disable this later for security reasons. This setting is only dangerous if you run an intentionally malicious code while its enabled. I promise my code is not dangerous.)

Step 3: Create a new module. This will open up a window in the VBA editor.
Type this:

```
Public Sub DoSQL()
Dim SQLa as String
Dim SQLb as String

SQLa = "INSERT INTO [newTable]([employeeID], [jobclassID]) SELECT DISTINCT dbo_Oracle.[Table A].[employeeID] FROM dbo_Oracle.[Table A] ORDER BY [jobclassID];"

DoCmd.RunSQL SQLa

SQLb = "INSERT INTO [newTable] ([jobpositionID]) SELECT DISTINCT dbo_Oracle.[Table B].[jobpositionID] FROM dbo_Oracle.[Table B] ORDER BY [jobpositionID];"

DoCmd.RunSQL SQLb
End Sub
```

---

NOTE: The SQL statements enclosed in "quotes" must be on a single line.

Step 4: Click save, and then click the little green arrow to run it.

Step 5: Once you get it to successfully populate the new table, you can delete the jobclassID column. But you should do a quick scan to make sure that the assigned jobpositionID's match the correct jobclassID

I hope this helps. If not, then reply with the information I asked about previously as well as what kind of error message(s) you get. This method worked for me in a similar situation. If this doesn't work for you, then perhaps we can see what slight modifications need to be made.

If for some reason it is taking forever to run, then press ctrl>alt>Del and quit Access from the Task manager (if you have a PC) If you have a mac then force quit by clicking and holding on the icon in the dock and click "Quit"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to query Oracle from MS Access. MS Access SQL is very limited, while Oracle's is very rich and much, much closer to the SQL standard. As you are querying an Oracle database, I surmise you have all Oracle SQL features available. Either directly or by creating a view in the Oracle database.

A mere join on jobclassID would give you all combinations, i.e. all cashiers with all cashier jobs etc. And a top 1 query (give me the first job you find for a person) on the other hand would lead to several persons getting the same job position.

A solution to join each person and each job position only once is to number the potential employees and the jobs, e.g. cashier persons 1, 2, 3, ... and cahier jobs 1, 2, 3, ... and then join on jobclassID plus number.

```
select
  e.employeeid,
  j.jobpositionid
from 
(
  select
    employeeid,
    jobclassid,
    row_number() over (partition by jobclassid order by employeeid) as rn
  from employee
) e
left outer join
(
  select
    jobpositionid,
    jobclassid,
    row_number() over (partition by jobclassid order by jobpositionid) as rn
  from job_position
) j using (jobclassid, rn)
order by e.employeeid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this self-join trick too:

```
select X1.employeeID, X2.jobPositionID
from 
(
select T1.jobClassID, T1.jobPositionID, count(*) as rankNum
from B T1 
inner join B T2 on T1.jobClassID = T2.jobClassID and T1.jobPositionID >= T2.jobPositionID
group by T1.jobClassID, T1.jobPositionID
) X2
inner join 
(
select T1.employeeID, T1.jobClassID, count(*) as rankNum
from A T1 
inner join A T2 on T1.jobClassID = T2.jobClassID and T1.employeeID >= T2.employeeID
group by T1.employeeID, T1.jobClassID
) X1 on X1.jobClassID = X2.jobClassID and X1.rankNum = X2.rankNum
order by X1.employeeID
```